# Yum equivalent of rpm --nopreun

Tags: linux, yum, rpm

I have a buggy RPM which deletes the installation files when it is upgraded. I want to run `yum update pkg-name` but I don't want to run the `%preun` section. Is this possible with yum? If so, what's the flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed the `yum-downloadonly` plugin:

`# yum install yum-downloadonly`

and then I told it to download the pkg to `/opt`:

`# yum update pkg-name -y --downloadonly --downloaddir=/opt`

The `-y` option means **"Assume yes"**

Then I executed the `rpm -i --nopreun /opt/pkgname`

Answer (score 4):

Not with `yum`, but you can download the rpm and try to run 
rpm with "`--noscripts`" option.

EDIT: to your comment, there is a `--nopreun` switch as well for rpm command

Comment: Yea, I need all scripts except the pre-un section :)

Comment: It's '--noscripts' NOT '--no-scripts', just fyi

Answer (score 3):

With yum, no, but you can use `yumdownloader` to retrieve the package and any dependencies (available in the `yum-utils` package), then run `rpm` manually.

Comment: Hmm, ok.. yum reinstall pkg-name seems to work too for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
yum --setopt=tsflags=noscripts remove $pkgname
```